# why does spark2.2 console sink need call parallelize function?

Tags: apache-spark

In spark2.2 console sink, we can see function `addBatch` is designed as follows.

```
// scalastyle:off println
data.sparkSession.createDataFrame(
    data.sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(data.collect()), data.schema)
    .show(numRowsToShow, isTruncated)
```

But I wonder why we don't make it like this:

```
data.show(numRowsToShow, isTruncated)
```

I think using parallelize will run 2 jobs which means it will cost more resouce and time. So I think `data.show(numRowsToShow, isTruncated)` should be more suitable.
Please tell me whether I am right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collect` is a workaround to solve a certain problems of the current implementation. [According to Michael Armbrust](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/cannot-call-explain-or-show-on-dataframe-in-structured-streaming-addBatch-dataframe-td21792.html):

> There is a little bit of weirdness to how we override the default query planner to replace it with an incrementalizing planner.  As such, calling any operation that changes the query plan (such as a LIMIT) would cause it to revert to the batch planner and return the wrong answer.  We should fix this before the finalize the Sink API.

Also:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16264
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21710

`paralelize` is just to get back to consistent `DataFrame` API.